# Statistics: Probability Theory

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following question here below.

[image: Research Study on Smoking Diagram]

Is the solution to this problem:

(1/10) / [(1/10)+(2/25)] = 5/9

Comment: Looks like there are $300$ smokers, $100$ of whom have heart disease, so...

Answer (score 2):

Restrict the population of interest to smokers only. For the purpose of this problem, we don't care about the rest of the population at the moment. We have 300 smokers total. Of those smokers, we know that 100 have heart disease. So, we have a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ that a randomly selected smoker has heart disease.